# How to search word in word list?

Tags: java, string

today I learn to write code puzzle word in java. I stress with search word in  a list and I want to search it only (Vertical,horizontal) but not diagonal. My code is not gave me  error and result. and can you help me to refresh it.

```
public class WordPuzzle {
    private final String puzzleString[][];
    private final int rowNumber;

    public WordPuzzle(String[][] puzzleString,int rowNumber){
        this.puzzleString=puzzleString;
        this.rowNumber=rowNumber;
    }
    public void showPuzzle(){

        for(int i=0;i<rowNumber;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<rowNumber;j++){
                System.out.print(" "+puzzleString[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public Set<String> searchWord(Set<String> word){
        Set<String> foundWord=new HashSet<String>();
        int minimumWordLength=findMinimumWordLenght(word);
        Set<String>compWord=CompatitableWord(minimumWordLength);
        for(String w:word){
            for(String posibleWord:compWord){
                if(posibleWord.contains(w) || posibleWord.contains(new StringBuffer(w).reverse())){
                    foundWord.add(w);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return foundWord;
    }
    private int findMinimumWordLenght(Set<String> wordLength){
        int minimumLenght=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(String w:wordLength){
            if(w.length()<minimumLenght){
                minimumLenght=w.length();
            }
        }
        return minimumLenght;
    }
    private Set<String> CompatitableWord(int minimumWordLength){
        Set<String>compWord=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        int puzzleLength=puzzleString.length;
        if(puzzleLength>=minimumWordLength){

            for(int i=0;i<puzzleLength;i++){
                if(puzzleString[i].length>=minimumWordLength){
                    compWord.add(new String(puzzleString[i].toString()));
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<puzzleLength;i++){
                StringBuffer tmp=new StringBuffer();
                for(int j=0;j<puzzleLength;j++){
                    tmp=tmp.append(puzzleString[j][i]);
                }
                compWord.add(new String(tmp));
            }
        }
        return compWord;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[][] a={{"g","y","r","a","r","b","i","l","e"},
                      {"u","a","a","n","c","h","o","r","i"},
                      {"i","b","y","d","v","e","x","t","r"},
                      {"t","z","c","h","y","n","e","q","u"},
                      {"a","m","a","n","g","o","d","v","q"},
                      {"r","n","i","h","p","l","o","d","l"},
                      {"f","o","r","e","s","t","u","d","y"},
                      {"j","d","l","w","a","r","c","h","u"},
                      {"h","a","v","g","h","y","e","t","y"}
                     };

        WordPuzzle pn=new WordPuzzle(a,9);
        pn.showPuzzle();
        Set<String> str=new HashSet<String>();
        str.add("library");
        Set<String>wordFound=pn.searchWord(str);
        for(String w:wordFound){
             System.out.println("Found"+pn.searchWord(str));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Last time I checked _and you help to refresh it_ is not a question. Can you edit your post to give a more specific question so that we can help you?

Comment: oh sorry, I mean can you help me find error in code above. because I run without error and result. and result it should be returned a string that found.

Comment: @nari puzzleString[][] is multidimensional array. Now in

CompatibleWord(int minimumWordLength)

you wrote 

compWord.add(new String(puzzleString[i].toString()));
i.e. 1 D array. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your program, because it is so complex and hardly. First, replace strings to chars: you should have matrix of char, `char[][] mat`. Second, save all rows and columns to `String`:

```
String[] rows = ... // use new String(mat[i]) 
String[] columns = ... // transform matrix and see solution for rows
```

After this, use `rows[i].indexOf` or  `columns[i].indexOf`.

Also, you can use `rows[i].reverse().indexOf` or  `columns[i].reverse().indexOf`.

Sorry for my bad English